# Defining functions that return a char used later in the main program

Tags: c, function, parameters, return-value, command-line-arguments

I am having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around calling functions and using them in the main program again later. I have not found an answer in depth to explain why this doesn't run. I understand that parameters belong inside of the called function parentheses, but I want the user input to begin in the called program. Is this even possible? Theoretically, the function would ask the user for a year, check that it is within certain parameters, then return it to the main function where I would like to eventually be able to store it in an array. For now, can someone please show me how I would make that work in this elementary program? Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

char year_info();

int main(void)
{
    int menu_selection;
    char year;

    printf("Please choose from the following menu: \n1. Insert a new movie\n2. Show movie\n3. List all\n4. Exit\n");
    scanf("%i", &menu_selection);
    switch (menu_selection)
    {
        case 1: year = year_info();
                printf("%c", year);
                break;
    }
}

char year_info()
{
    int year_input;
    printf("\nYear: ");
    scanf("%i", &year_input);
    if (year_input > 2016 || year_input < 1920)
    {
        printf("Sorry, I do not recognize this command. Please try again.\n");
    } 
    else
    {
        int year = year_input;
        return year;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `char` is (usually) an 8-bit integer. Depending on the compiler it can take values from -128 to 127, or from 0 to 255. The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format `"%i"` reads into  an `int` variable, and `int` are usually *32* bits wide, going from minus 2 billion to plus two billion. Surely you can see some problems with trying to fit a value like one or two thousand into a variable which can not hold that large values.

Comment: `char year_info();` --> `int year_info();`, `char year_imput;` --> `int year_imput;`, `scanf("%i", year_imput);` --> `scanf("%i",  &year_imput);` and there is a path that does not return a value.

Comment: So should I be using %d instead?

Comment: Other than the above problem (and others), declaring a prototype before calling a function will be okay, provided you define the function somewhere else in your program.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't *run* because you're passing `scanf` the variable, but you should pass the address of the variable, i.e. use:

```
scanf("%i", &something);
```

instead of `scanf("%i", something);`

---

Also, as others pointed out, you're mixing `char` and `int` too liberally, so it won't work as expected.

`year` and `year_imput` can't be chars because they won't hold values large enough, you'll need at least a short.

Answer (score 0):

You had 2 errors.

```
scanf("%i", &menu_selection);


scanf("%i", &year_imput);
```

You need to use the & to pass the address of the variables to `scanf()`.

**Edit**: However, I would have used an integer for that, because a `scanf("%c", &something)` will only recognize the first char you enter, and not the whole string, even if that happened you can't do `if (year_imput > 2016 || year_imput < 1920)` between strings, you can do that with chars, but again, they can only store one character, so I would have done your program like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int year_info();

int main() {
    int menu_selection;
    int year;

    printf("Please choose from the following menu: \n1. Insert a new movie\n2. Show movie\n3. List all\n4. Exit\n");
    scanf("%i", &menu_selection);

    switch (menu_selection) {
        case 1:
                year = year_info();
                printf("%i", year);
                break;
        default:
                break;
    }

    return 0;
}

int year_info() {
    int year_imput;
    printf("\nYear: ");
    scanf("%i", &year_imput);

    if (year_imput > 2016 || year_imput < 1920) {
        printf("Sorry, I do not recognize this command. Please try again.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return year_imput;
}
```

Comment: I am required to store the years as chars and eventually place them in an array. How would that work in this program? Could the function return type be char and then cast the int as a char in the "else" section of the program?

Comment: Then you should store the year as a [String](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm) which is basically an array of chars.